# Push notifications registration in electron using APNS does not work

Tags: macos, electron, apple-push-notifications

I started building an electron app which is supposed to receive push notifications for critical events from a server I control. It has to work on all 3 major desktop platforms (windows, macOS, linux).

The application has a few restrictions:

- I cannot use [electron-push-receiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-push-receiver), as it is a reverse engineered solution, and might unexpectedly break in the future.
- I cannot use WebSockets or MQTT to receive the notifications because of scaling issues on my back end.

I started experimenting with using [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) on MacOS, because [Electron seems to support it out of the box](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/push-notifications). However,  I have not managed to get it to work. When calling the function, I get one of the two errors:

```
[Error: 13 NSOSStatusErrorDomain {
    NSDebugDescription = "Bundle identifier mismatch";
}]
```

or

```
Error: 13 NSOSStatusErrorDomain {
NSDebugDescription = "Application not properly entitled for push notifications.";
}
```

I have created a new identifier, lets call it `bundle.id` on my apple developer account. I have created a developer certificate, called `Apple Development: Company (XXXXXX)`, a push certificate called `Apple Sandbox Push Services: bundle.id` and a provisioning profile with push notifications enabled. Inspecting the provisioning profile and looking at its entitlements:

```xml
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
        <string>development</string>
                
        <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID.bundle.id</string>
                
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
           <string>TEAMID.*</string>
        </array>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID</string>

    </dict>
```

I have also created a `test.entitlements.plist` file by copying the [default entitlements file](https://github.com/electron/osx-sign/blob/main/entitlements/default.darwin.plist) from the `osx-sign` package and adding the push notification entitlement to it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>

    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.bluetooth</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.print</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.personal-information.location</key>
    <true/>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my forge config file. If I add the entitlements file manually and run `yarn make` and execute the app, I get the `Bundle identifier mismatch` error, if I do not add that file (by omitting `optionsForFile`), I get the `Not entitled to notifications` error. Running with `yarn start` always gives the `Bundle identifier mismatch` error.

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    appBundleId: 'bundle.id',
    osxSign: {
      identity: 'Apple Development: Company (XXXXXX)',
      provisioningProfile: './path-to-profile',
      optionsForFile: (filePath) => {
        return {
          entitlements: './test.entitlements.plist',
        }
      },
      type:'development'
    }
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "electron-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.1.1",
    "electron": "^24.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "bundle.id",
    "forceCodeSigning": true
  }
}
```

And finally, here is the part where I try and register:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, pushNotifications } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  pushNotifications.registerForAPNSNotifications().then((token) => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', token);
  }).catch(e => { console.error(e) })
```

I also tried creating a native MacOS app in Xcode using [this guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app), using the same provisioning profile and certificate, and the APNS registration works fine.

```swift
@main
struct testApp: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    init() {
        NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I am failing to configure my entitlements correctly, but I failed to discover how.
I am totally new to Electron and desktop development.

- What can be done to make the registration work? Am I missing something with the signing part?
- What is the difference between running `electron-forge start` and `electron-forge make && out/executable.app`? Can this be made to work even when using `electron-forge start`?